# Show not only accept rate, but also number of questions asked

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, accept-rate

I like the "accept rate" info on a user's questions - but how about also showing how many questions the user has asked?

Especially for those notorious non-accepters, that information might be helpful and encouraging them to finally get off their b*** and start accepting people's responses to their answers....

Just a thought.....

Marc

Comment: Finally get off their boot?

Comment: Finally get off their back? Off their boat? Bean?

Comment: bran, boys, bork, borg, barn, bank, bang, bird, bone, bean, beer, bear, bass, buns, oh my god the possibilities are endless.

Comment: The censorship is getting out of hand!

Comment: 'off their bots'. Double entendre.

Comment: Declined as [accept rate is no longer shown with on the usercard for a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/140951).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you hover over the accept rate, it will show you how many questions they have asked (and are counted toward the accept rate) as well as how many of those they've accepted.

[image: nuts to the accept rate]

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner.

Comment: excellent ! Thanks - didn't know that was implemented already :-)