# Show number of questions along with accept rate

Tags: feature-request, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show not only accept rate, but also number of questions asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24130/show-not-only-accept-rate-but-also-number-of-questions-asked)

I think it would make sense to show how many questions the user asked along with the percentage of accepted questions. Something like "accepted 95% of 154 questions" or the absolute values: "accept rate: 63/70". This is the first thing I look up whenever I have the feeling the OP is trying to get his job/homework done by others.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24130/show-not-only-accept-rate-but-also-number-of-questions-asked/

Comment: @random: thx, couldn't find that one.

Comment: yes, just mouseover the text and the tooltip contains this info.