# Number of Questions & Answers on hover of Username

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, information-display

I don't think myself to be eligible to suggest something at this reputation level. But, I found this helpful if it can be implemented.

I kindly request you to correct me if I am wrong with this suggestion.

My suggestion is:

**To ToolTip the number of questions & answers the user has asked/answered while hovering the userName.**

The reputation is shown on howering the Username of the Comment. And the Accept Rate is shown while hovering the Accept Rate. I have also seen [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24130/show-not-only-accept-rate-but-also-number-of-questions-asked) question. But, this is for the accept rate. However, it shows the number of Answers as well, but still I think it would be better to display the question-answer count as well.

I don't know if this is proper suggestion or not. I welcome your view with this suggestion.

Comment: Nice suggestion, definite +1 for that.. but it's `feature-request` rather than `discussion`. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is kind of a good suggestion. Usually when you see accept rate from user, we drilldown into his profile to find out how many questions he has asked to get such a low accept rate. If it is more than 10, then the community seldom help such people.

To reduce the effort of drilling down into user profile, I think if you hover on accept rate of user, it should show how many eligible questions has the user asked for getting this accept rate. Note, it should count only eligible questions of the OP and not all questions.

**EDIT**: As @ChrisF mentions in comments below and as checked on SO, the hover on accept rate already shows this information of how many answers have been accepted by user out of eligible questions.

The number of answers given by user should not matter and hence it is not required to be shown in the hover. However, it would be interesting to show the number of upvotes the user has given to community. This would also show if the user knows about upvoting or not.

Comment: Once again thanks Sachin. However, cannot +1 here, as "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" :)

Comment: :) This is not for reputation as I had already mentioned in my profile. Just simply joking with Sachin... :) Thanks a lot to you to for support !!!

Comment: @info - :) thanks. Now you can upvote in meta as well as on SO... :) Good suggestion tough.

Comment: Your Pleasure !

Comment: @ChrisF - Never noticed it. You think of it and its already there ;) how about having no. of upvotes too?

Comment: I am aware about that. I have also linked a question in my question. But, that is what actually the question i.e. of showing number of Questions !!! & not only the answers...

Comment: @infoSetu - The current tooltip is showing correctly and exactly the info required to be seen by the community. Showing total no. of questions would not be useful. Also it is not showing answers in tooltip, it shows the no. of questions to which OP has accepted answers, which is again useful.

Comment: Agree ! It is... while hovering the Accept rate & is of same Useful. I am suggesting to show Number of Questions & Answer by User while hovering Username.